# How to remove CR LF in nifi

Tags: java, apache-nifi

I have a csv which has a CRLF when i checked in notepad++ due to which the data corresponding to that column is populating in next column and the same is happening with the next column value.

I want to replace that with Replace text in Apache-Nifi. Any leads?

Example below:

> **Name,id,product,product_id,email,phone_no,fax_no**
>
> John,1,2,3,**CRLF**
>
> x@p.com, +212 -909-9008, +212 -909-9009 -- it is coming in next line.

Comment: edit your question and add additional details. What's coming, what do you expect, where you could have unwanted CRLF,...

Answer (score 2):

You can use replaceTextprocessor line by line mode.

replace \n with '' or any other value.

Comment: Its not for one row, I have many rows in a csv. if I replace \n with '' all the records will come in single row.

Comment: The answer is right, the replacetext processor accepts a regular expression, you only need to define which are the rules.